# Designing panels on form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three panels docked as follow:

```
1 - panel1 - Right
2 - panel2 - Bottom
3 - panel3 - Left
```

These panels are created according same order.
I would like `panel3` to extend to bottom at the same length like `panel1` How to achieve that?

[image]

Comment: by adding then in order 1,3,2

Comment: adding in order is one way, but after adding them, docking can simply controled by sending panels to back, or bringing to front. the one in the back will use the all space, then others (in the same order)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just right click on panel 3 and select "Send to Back" in the context menu that opens, the control that is on the back has priority in docking to the one which is in front.

[image]